# Will Windows 8 reset delete other partitions in one hard drive?

Tags: windows-8, reset

I want to reinstall my windows 8 system using the reset function. I have two partitions in my hard drive: `C:` and `D:`. Windows 8 is installed in the `C:` drive. If I reset my computer, will the files in `D:` be deleted as well?

Comment: refresh keeps your files and gives the system a fresh start; reset erases all data and you start anew.  when choosing the reset option, make sure you select `Just remove my files` instead of `Clean the drive fully` or your whole partition tables on the physical disk will be gone.